# Bash script - sshing into one computer and then immediately into that comupter's network's modem

Tags: bash, ssh, networking, scripting

I am currently attempting to automagically reboot my modem that for some reason or another will only allow certain types of small Linux OS's to ssh into it - and not the one I am using. So, rebooting that modem currently (manually) requires me to ssh into a third-party on my network that *is* allowed to ssh into the modem, ssh-ing into the modem from there, and then rebooting it with the

```
reboot
```

command.

This would work, but I would also like the modem to auto-reboot every two hours, which means I need to automate this whole "ssh-ing into the modem" process.

I would like to write a script that will ssh into the third-party, and then immediately ssh into the modem from the third-party to reboot it.
However, after telling the script to ssh into the third-party, I'm lost as to how I also make it ssh into the modem from the third party.

So far I'm using sshpass to automatically input the password and this is what is looks like

```
sshpass -p "third_party_password" ssh thirdparty@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
sshpass -p "modem_password" ssh modem@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Although obviously the second line never runs and that's why I'm asking this.

Please let me know if there is any other info I can provide. 
Also, if what I am asking is not possible, are there any other suggestions as to how I could accomplish the automatic modem reboot from the linux command line I'm trying to use?

Comment: Typically `expect` is used to automate software that asks for passwords (e.g. the login to the modem and then interaction with the modem cli). Or, can public key authentication be setup on the modem? (And can the `reboot` command be passed as an argument to the ssh to the modem?)

Comment: You use `-L` for this, but i don't understand what you're talking about with *only allow certain types of small Linux OSs*. That doesn't make any sense. Might it actually have to do with the encryption method used?

Comment: @mikeserv is on the right track.  Tweaking `ssh` options sounds easier than creating a proxy for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
sshpass -p "third_party_password" ssh thirdparty@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'sshpass -p "modem_password" ssh modem@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx reboot'
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could setup login by ssh-keys, if this is possible for you, and then just run `ssh thirdparty@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'ssh modem@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx reboot'`.